# How to get a link to a diagram in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I have a project documentation generated by Doxygen and few handwritten pages in markdown, where I'd like to refer some of the autogenerated diagrams (e.g. class and collaboration).

I am looking for references(anchors) to these images... The simplest way is to refer the class, but this brings too many links to the page with the diagram. If there is a way to get the name of the image, then it will be possible even to add it to the page (in markdown).

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Did you look at the `\anchor` command?

Comment: @albert, would you please tell me how to apply the `@anchor` command in this context (for example to an autogenerated class diagram)?

Comment: Ah good point, I was thinking just about user inserted images but this is indeed not what you stated in your question (didn't read the question properly enough, sorry). Indeed at the moment I think that the best / only way is to refer the class / function where the diagram resides. You could place your own anchor in these functions and refer  to these, maybe an enhancement request for some automatic anchor in the doxygen issue tracker is in it place, the problem will be how to refer to these functions (a generated name is not always that easy to guess for the user. continuing...

Comment: What do you mean with "The simplest way is to refer the class, but this brings too many links to the page with the diagram" especially the part " but this brings too many links to the page with the diagram"

Comment: @albert , The point is that I can do it as you mentioned, by referencing the class for example, but in this case, to see the diagram , one needs to go to other, (class) page, then to go back to the original page... I just want to reuse the autogenerated image, and for that reason I need to have the link to that image.

Comment: When I understand it correctly you want to have the, in this case, class diagram included on multiple places. For this you need the, auto generated, name of diagram or another mechanism to copy the image. The only way I see at the moment is to, test, generate the documentation, obtain the name of the image (and also part of the path in case you use `CREATE_SUBDIRS=YES`), add this image by means of either the `\image` command or with `<A href=....`.